# Cant set numbers as document path Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have made a function that fetches users from an endpoint, I succefully retrieved the users id, the ids are this ones

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Now, I want those id's to be the document path to store the data, I have made this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonresponse.length; i++) {
  var obj = jsonresponse[i];
  var docid = obj.id
  db.collection("users").doc(docid).set(obj)
}
```

The output of the ids is ok, I have logged them out and they are working, but the document cant be generated with those numbers.

This is what I get from the console log error

> Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path.
>   Path must be a non-empty string.

Edit

```
console.log("id",docid)
```

[image]

Comment: Log the value of `docid`. Is it exactly what you expect when an error occurs?

Comment: What is the value of `docid`?

Comment: yes, docid logs out from 1 to 10 , just numbers

Comment: Endpoint : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Comment: added an image of the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have an array with ids, just do this:

```
jsonresponse = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for (var i = 0; i < jsonresponse.length; i++) {
  var obj = jsonresponse[i];
  var docid = obj.id
  db.collection('users').doc(""+docid).set(obj);
}
```

how are you testing that? maybe postman or something is sending the json as text

Comment: maybe like that?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could take the following approach to writing `users` data to  firebase, by first obtaining a [`ref()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#ref) to the target document (via the document path that matches your desired pattern), and then calling `.set()` on the document ref:

```
for (const obj of jsonresponse) {

  /* 
  Obtain target document ref from path that is obj id, relative to collection type 
  */
  db.ref(`users/${ obj.id }`).set(obj);
}
```

Comment: nope, but I dont need to, since if I change that obj.id inside doc with any string it will create and push the data without a problem